# How many arguments does an anonymous function expect in clojure?

Tags: clojure, arguments, anonymous-function

How does Clojure determine how many arguments an anonymous function (created with the `#...` notation) expect?

```
user=> (#(identity [2]) 14)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of args (1) passed to: user$eval3745$fn (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`#(println "Hello, world!")`        -> no arguments

`#(println (str "Hello, " % "!"))`     -> 1 argument (`%` is a synonym for `%1`)

`#(println (str %1 ", " %2 "!"))` -> 2 arguments

and so on. Note that you do not have to use all `%n`s, the number of arguments expected is defined by the highest n. So `#(println (str "Hello, " %2))` still expects two arguments.

You can also use `%&` to capture rest args as in

`(#(println "Hello" (apply str (interpose " and " %&))) "Jim" "John" "Jamey")`.

From the [Clojure docs](http://clojure.org/reader):

```
Anonymous function literal (#())
#(...) => (fn [args] (...))
where args are determined by the presence of argument literals taking the 
form %, %n or  %&. % is a synonym for %1, %n designates the nth arg (1-based), 
and %& designates a rest arg. This is not a replacement for fn - idiomatic 
used would be for very short one-off mapping/filter fns and the like. 
#() forms cannot be nested.
```

Comment: What is the points to put extra parenthesis around println in the first 3 code examples?

Answer (score 11):

It is giving you the error that you passed one argument to your anonymous function that was expecting zero.

**The arity of an anonymous function is determined by the highest argument referenced inside.**

e.g.

`(#(identity [2]))` -> arity 0, 0 arguments must be passed

`(#(identity [%1]) 14)` -> arity 1, 1 argument must be passed

`(#(identity [%]) 14)` -> (`%` is an alias for `%1` if and only if the arity is 1), 1 argument must be passed

`(#(identity [%1 %2]) 14 13)` or

`(#(identity [%2]) 14 13)` -> arity 2, 2 arguments must be passed

`(#(identity [%&]) 14)` -> arity n, any number of arguments can be passed

Comment: Cool, neat example with `%&`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You need to refer to the arguments with %1, %2 etc. to cause the function to require that many arguments.