# Clojure: How does filter interact with logic?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to learn Clojure, so I figured a good way to start would be to work through the project Euler challenges with it, and the first challenge is summing all of the number below 1000 that are divisible by 3 or 5.

My original code was:

```
(defn div3 [input-no] (zero? (mod input-no 3)))
(defn div5 [input-no] (zero? (mod input-no 5)))
(reduce + (filter (or div3 div5) (range 1 1000)))
```

But that didn't work, and it turned out that the filter would just return a list of numbers divisible by 3, and not those divisible by 5.

I changed my code to:

```
(defn div3or5 [input-no] (or (div3 input-no) (div5 input-no)))
(reduce + (filter div3or5 (range 1 1000)))
```

Which got the right result, but I don't know why my original code didn't work.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Another way to learn Clojure is to find a project you'd do in another language -- for me it would have been implemented in C or r Python -- and write that in Clojure. For me, it was taking .csv input, forming and sending http requests from the .csv input data, retrieving the results, and, based on them, writing out a different .csv file.

Comment: For Clojure http://www.4clojure.com/ (no pun intended) is good, the web interface makes it really easy!

Comment: i'm curious if this was just a mistake (which is ok - no criticism intended) or whether there is some language where what you typed would have made sense.  were you expecting `or` to combine predicates because you see that behaviour elsewhere?  if so, where?  thanks...

Comment: I thought I could use or like:
if( Function1(x) || Function2(y))
where Functions 1 and 2 both return booleans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just evaluate `(or div3 div5)` in the REPL you can see what is happening:

```
=> (or div3 div5)
#<user$div3 user$div3@73305c>
```

That is, `or` is evaluating to the function `div3` (which `filter` is then using, giving the behaviour you describe).

The reason for this is `or` will return its first non-falsy argument (i.e. the first argument that isn't `nil` or `false`); in this case, the arguments are two function objects and a function object is not `nil` or `false`.

To put it another way, the `or` is happening on the functions themselves, not the results of the functions. As Paul said, you can use an anonymous function to make `or` act on the results rather than the functions themselves.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are running into is that `filter` expects a predicate (a function taking an input and returning true or false) as its first argument. But while `div3` and `div5` are functions you can't simply combine them with `or`. You need to construct a new function that takes one argument and feeds this to both `div3` and `div5` and calls `or` and the results of both.

Fortunately this is easy to do in Clojure, try

```
(filter #(or (div3 %) (div5 %)) (range1 1000))
```

`#()` is shorthand for defining a function inline (also called a *lambda*) and you can get to the first argument with `%1` to the second with `%2` and so on. If there is only one argument then you can use `%` for `%1` [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7841643/346587).

You may also want to understand that `#()` is just syntactic sugar for the `fn` form which
looks like this: `(fn [arg1 arg2 ... & restArgs] (forms))`. `#()` has some limitations (for example it can't be nested).

Comment: In Clojure 1.3, you can use `(filter (some-fn div3 div5) (range 1 1000))` too.

Comment: Sorry - your answer was helpful, its just the last paragraph of the other answer nailed it.

Comment: @Peter No worries, I agree that the last paragraph of dbaupp answer hits the nail on the head. Enjoy clojure!