# Counting a sequence in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm solving [Problem 22](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/22) from the 4Clojure site asking me to write a function that counts the elements in a sequence. Because I messed around with Haskell at one point, I know that using `fold` is probably the way to go about doing that. After reading about it, I've come to the understanding that I should be using `reduce` for the same purpose. Here's the answer I submitted:

```
#(reduce inc 0 %)
```

The reasoning behind this is to iterate the list, and call `inc` each time on the value which is initially 0. However, this does not work. The site is complaining that the "Wrong number of args (2) passed to: core$inc". So I tried adding parens around `inc`:

```
#(reduce (inc) 0 %)
```

Now it thinks zero arguments are being passed to `inc`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*So I tried adding parens around inc...*

Please, **don't** use parens in clojure **ever** for the purpose of guiding the compiler/interpretator. In clojure every parenthesis counts and this way you're just calling a function with zero arguments.

Now, take a look at the [clojure doc on reduce](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/reduce)

> If val is supplied, returns the result of applying f to val and the
>   first item in coll, then applying f to that result and the 2nd item,
>   etc.

So when you write

```
(reduce inc 0 [1 2 3])
```

what actually happens is

```
(inc 
   (inc 
      (inc 0 1) 2) 3)
```

Proper function might look like

```
#(reduce 
    (fn [c _] (inc c))
     0 %)
```

Comment: Works when the coll contains numbers, but not characters.

Comment: @RossPresser oh, I forgot about initial value, fixed now: `(reduce (fn [c _] (inc c)) 0 [\a \b \c])` will yield 3. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assume the list is

```
[1 2 3 4]
```

In your first example, you are telling reduce to execute these:

```
(inc 0 1)
(inc 0 2)
(inc 0 3)
(inc 0 4)
```

Clearly inc is being passed two arguments here, when it requires one.

In your second attempt, you are telling reduce that (inc) will return a function which is then to be used with the value and the list.  (inc) is a call to the inc function with zero arguments.

What you need for the first argument to reduce is a function that takes two values and returns the first value incremented by one.

Answer (score 2):

Clojure's `reduce` can be thought as similar to haskell's left-fold function `foldl`.
The haskell way of counting items in a list `xs` would be something like this

`foldl (const . (+1)) 0 xs`

which is better understood as `foldl (\acc _ -> acc + 1) 0 xs`.

The idea is to increment the first operand in the fold function and so i'd be tempted to write it as

`(reduce #(inc (%1)) 0 xs)`

except that is wrong as the arity of the anonymous function is determined by the [highest argument referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841643/how-many-arguments-does-an-anonymous-function-expect-in-clojure) in the expression and our fold function has to have an arity of 2.

So, a clever workaround:
`(reduce #(inc (first %&)) 0 xs)`

Answer (score 1):

I have been going through the problem list learning clojure too.  Came up with this answer to that problem:

```
reduce + (#(for [o %] 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach by converting sequence to Java array and calling alength function:

```
#(alength (to-array %))
```