# How do I make a literal function that takes no args and return a constant value?

Tags: clojure, compojure-api

I'm trying to learn Clojure, and am blocked up around the literal function syntax.  I can't figure out what the literal function equivalent of `(defn fourteen [] 14)` is.

```
(def fourteen (fn [] 14))
;; => #'user/fourteen
(fourteen)
;; => 14
(defn defn-fourteen [] 14)
;; => #'user/defn-fourteen
(defn-fourteen)
;; => 14
(def literal-14 #(14))
;; => #'user/literal-14
(literal-14)
;; ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  user/literal-14 (form-init2956929406616221071.clj:1)
```

I don't think this is a dup of [How many arguments does an anonymous function expect in clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841643/how-many-arguments-does-an-anonymous-function-expect-in-clojure), but maybe it is and I just don't possess the experience to recognize that.

How, or can, I def literal-14 to allow the `(literal-14)` invocation to work?

Comment: (fn [& args] x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`14` isn't a function, but `do` or `->` will do in a pinch:

```
#(do 14)
#(-> 14)
```

Comment: `#(do 14)` works, `#(identity 14)` is perhaps bit more clear, and of course `(constantly 14)` is correct

Comment: So the first 'thing' inside a function literal has to be a function?  I don't fully understand, but both the do variant and the identity variants do what I am looking for, but I am still a little fuzzy on what an anonymous function literal is.

Comment: @BobKuhar Try `(macroexpand '#(14))`, etc.

Comment: @A.Webb ```(macroexpand '#(14))```, results in ```(fn* [] (14))```, which does make clear the List aspect @Elogent speaks of.  But now the fn* itself is a new question.  Its a different fn?  What does the * do there?  I can't get any doc on it.  I am a rat in a maze!  Thanks for your help, though.  Maybe the clouds will clear.

Comment: @BobKuhar `fn*` is the special form on top of which the `fn` macro is built. For simple cases like this one, they are equivalent.

Answer (score 12):

As [A. Webb pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35737118/how-do-i-make-a-literal-function-that-takes-no-args-and-return-a-constant-value#comment59148680_35737193), `constantly` is the most idiomatic way to write this:

```
(def fourteen (constantly 14))
```

The problem with the anonymous function literal is that it *always* expands to a function whose body is a list:

```
'#(stuff and things) ;=> (fn* [] (stuff and things))
```

So here's what's happening in your attempt:

```
'#(14) ;=> (fn* [] (14))
```

There is no way to get rid of those parentheses. You could hack your way around them using `do` or `identity` or something like that, but the bottom line is that if you need to write an anonymous function whose body isn't suited to being written as a list, you shouldn't use the literal syntax.