# Declare dummy (unused) parameters for Clojure anonymous function

Tags: clojure, arguments, anonymous-function

As also explained in the answers [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841643/how-many-arguments-does-an-anonymous-function-expect-in-clojure), Clojure determines the number of parameters of an anonymous function (defined through `#()`), by the maximal parameter index referenced in the body (e.g. if the maximal referenced parameter is `%4`, then that anonymous function has 4 parameters).

Question: is there some syntax to tell the Clojure compiler that an anonymous function expects one parameter, even not referencing that parameter? Or, in this case, the only "clean way"* is to use the [fn syntax](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/fn)? (* "Clean way": I'm aware that in most cases, you could reference the dummy parameter without affecting the function -- see below, but I would like to avoid such workarounds.)

My use case: I have a function `(defn foo [predicate])`, where `predicate` expects exactly one argument, and I would like to test `foo` with a predicate that always returns `true`. (I.e., something like `#(true)`.) This causes an `ArityException` since the interpreter thinks that `#(true)` expects zero arguments.

In this particular case, I could use some clever hack like `#(or true %)`, but:

1. It is almost as much to type as the `fn`-variant.
2. I'm interested if there is a generic solution.

Edit: so to be clear, I'm looking for something like this:

`#[1](true)  ;; the anonymous function takes one parameter`

Comment: About the specific, not the general question – Clojure 1.9 will include the predicate you are looking for as [`any?`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/any?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Just use `fn`. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a constant return you are after you can use [`constantly`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/constantly):

```
(map (constantly 10) '(1 2 3 4 5)) 
; ==> (10 10 10 10 10)
```

If it's not you can use `fn` with a rest argument:

```
(fn [& _] 
 some-side-effect-expression)
; ==> non functional value
```

In fact this can be done on higher order functions where you don't need all the passes arguments:

```
(some-fun (fn [a b & _] (+ a b)) '(1 2 3 4 5))
; ==> (3 5 7 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on the `#( ... )` syntax, you can write

```
#(do % true)
```

... incurring no run-time penalty, whatever you want to return.

But `(constantly true)`, as [@Sylvester](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41910523/1562315) suggests, is idiomatic, and accepts any argument list:

```
((constantly true) 1 2 "Buckle my shoe");true
```