# How do I pass dummy arguments to clojure lambdas?

Tags: lambda, clojure, functional-programming, jvm, lisp

I'm writing some code using Reagent, and part of that involves writing some callbacks and state manipulation.

A few of those places will invoke functions with default arguments, and I don't want to do anything with them. I just want to return a constant value.

When I use something like `#(true)`, for instance, I'll get an exception, and I have to write `(fn [_] true)`.  Is there a way for the lambda shorthand to know it's getting a parameter and not using it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declare dummy (unused) parameters for Clojure anonymous function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41909132/declare-dummy-unused-parameters-for-clojure-anonymous-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#(do % true)
```

But honestly, I just write the full version without the macro. It makes it much clearer what the intent is.

It's a shame Clojure doesn't seem to have a version of Haskell's `const` function. It takes a value and returns a function that throws away its argument and returns the value. Very handy for situations like this. It's trivial to write your own version for your library however:

```
(defn const [value]
    (fn [_] value))

(some-hof (const true))
```

With some creativity, it probably wouldn't be difficult to make `const` support any number of arguments.

---

Edit:

@amalloy pointed out that Clojure does in fact have such a function! `core/constantly`.

Comment: clojure.core/constantly

Comment: @amalloy Pfft. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks.